# Looking for the correct syntax for a swagger /document POST from a REST client

Tags: rest, swagger, document

I am sending a post to /document (swagger), which should upload a document using the body content of

```
{
    "Application": "tickets",
    "File": "some binary data"
}
```

The back in is using swagger /document so I believe my headers are not coming over correctly.

The problem is I am not getting the correct combination of the headers that need to be sent over:

```
Authorization : xxxx; 
Content-Type : multipart/form-data;
Content-Type : image/png;
Content-Type : application/json;
FileName : file_name
```

Response:

```
415 Unsupported Media Type
```

[image]

Comment: After talking with vendor they suggested using multipart/form-data as a post to swagger /document.

Does anyone have a proper formatted POST to swagger openAPI that will upload a file within C# ?

Answer (score 0):

```
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"file");
            byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(fi.FullName);

            ByteArrayContent byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileContents);
            byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                FileName = fi.Name, 
            };

            MultipartFormDataContent multiPartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            multiPartContent.Add(new StringContent("document storage"), "Application");
            multiPartContent.Add(byteArrayContent, "File");

            string header = string.Format("WRAP access_token=\"{0}\"", "xxxx");

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/document");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", header);
            request.Content = multiPartContent;

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            try
            {
                Task<HttpResponseMessage> httpRequest = httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, CancellationToken.None);
                HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = httpRequest.Result;
                HttpStatusCode statusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode;
                HttpContent responseContent = httpResponse.Content;

                if (responseContent != null)
                {
                    Task<String> stringContentsTask = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    String stringContents = stringContentsTask.Result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```